# proof of convergence in probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be i.i.d. random variables taking values in the set of natural number $\mathbb{N}$. Assume that $\mathbb{P}(X_1=i)=p_i>0$ for $i\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $D_n$ denote the carinality of the set $\{X_1,X_2,...,X_n\}$. Prove $(i)$, $D_n\rightarrow\infty$ a.s.; $(ii)$, $D_n/n\rightarrow 0$ in probability. Can one strengthen $(ii)$ to a.s. convergence?

Comment: Please include the steps you've tried in this multi-part problem.  No sense in having a Reader retrace all your work.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the second convergence can be almost surely

Fix $\epsilon >0$. Let $\tau$ be the first moment when the total probability of elements in $D_n$ is greater than $1 - \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.  By the fact that every element will eventually fall into $D_n$, we know $\tau$ is finite almost surely. To strictly prove it, begin with the element with biggest probability, then that with second biggest probability etc.

By the strong law of large number $\limsup\dfrac{D_n - D_\tau}{n - \tau} < \dfrac{\epsilon}{2} $, since after $\tau$, for each step the probability that $D_n$ increase by 1 is less than $\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$

The above limit is also limsup of $\dfrac{D_n}{n}$.

Comment: By the way, why can you apply strong law of large number to $\limsup \frac{D_n-D_\tau}{n-\tau}$. I don't understant.

Comment: By the way, why can you apply strong law of large number to $\limsup\frac{D_n-D_\tau}{n-\tau}$. I don't understant.

Comment: @Shine  My arguments are indeed not rigorous. The idea is that after $\tau$, each increment is dominated by a Bernoulli variable with paramter $\epsilon/2$.

Comment: Yes. For different increments are not independent, so you can't use SLLN.

Comment: Then how to explain this.

Comment: @Shine increments are not independent, but all the dominant Bernoulli's are

Comment: Yes. I understand this. Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Answer on (i):

$\left\{ D_{n}\rightarrow\infty\right\} ^{c}=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left\{ X_{n}\leq k\right\} $
so that $P\left(\left\{ D_{n}\rightarrow\infty\right\} ^{c}\right)\leq\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left\{ X_{n}\leq k\right\} \right)$.

For a fixed $k$ we find $P\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left\{ X_{n}\leq k\right\} \right)\leq P\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{m}\left\{ X_{n}\leq k\right\} \right)=\left(p_{1}+\cdots+p_{k}\right)^{m}$
for any $m$.

Here $p_{1}+\cdots+p_{k}<1$ so $m\rightarrow\infty$
makes clear that $P\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left\{ X_{n}\leq k\right\} \right)=0$.

Comment: Thank you! For $(i)$, you present a brilliant solution.